# Comparison woes

Tags: php, string, comparison, boolean

This is driving me crazy! I have a form and am supposed to do some validation on a text input called "range".

```
    function splitRange($range){
      if($range == ''){
        $returnedValue = '';
        return $returnedValue;
      }

      // some other code here
      return false;
    }    

    // ----------------

    $myRange = splitRange($_POST['range']);

    if($myRange == false){
      echo 'error';
    }
```

This keeps returning false and echoing 'error' when "range" is left blank!

Comment: if($myRange===false) as blank is classed as false. === means type cast too

Comment: is `$range` the empty string, or does it contain some spaces?

Comment: As has been explained, you must use exact equivalence. This code block should help you understand. http://codepad.org/7sJjkoNF  
Note that it returns 1, meaning that it evaluates to true, if you use `===`, it will evaluate to false.

Comment: look at this for comparisons http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your final comparison at the end states

```
if($myRange == false){
  echo 'error';
}
```

Which means "if `$myRange` is false-y, echo 'error'"

In other words,

```
if ($myRange == "")
```

and

```
if ($myRange == false)
```

are equivalent.

If you want it to compare whether `$myRange` is a boolean `false`, use

```
if($myRange === false)
```

Comment: === matches value and type. i.e. If both are considered 'false' and both are boolean. This will work with non-boolean types too, like string, integer etc..

Comment: Thank you for expounding on my meaning. +1!